# Estimating the protein concentration of an unpure protein solution

Tags: physical-chemistry, biochemistry, concentration

I'm confused on this problem for estimating protein concentration. Upon first glance, it looks like a simple Beer's law problem. but then there's the issue that the protein is not pure. How do I account for that?

> E. coli Maltose binding protein, like alkaline Phosphatase is a periplasmic protein. Audrey, has a solution containing solublized E. coli periplasmic proteins and maltose binding protein and she just read the absorbance of the solution at $280~\mathrm{nm}$ which was $0.84$, path length $1~\mathrm{cm}$.
>   Help Audrey estimate the protein concentration of her solution. Also note Audrey knows the extinction coefficient for maltose binding protein ($\mathrm{MW} \approx43,000$) is $32,290~\mathrm{M^{-1}cm^{-1}}$.
>   (Hint: not pure protein solution.)

As mentioned above I think it would just be Beer's law
\begin{align}
A &= \epsilon cl\\
A &= 0.84\\
l &= 1~\mathrm{cm}\\
\epsilon &= 32,290~\mathrm{M^{-1}cm^{-1}}\\
\end{align}

Solving for $c$ gives $0.26~\mathrm{mM}$. My guess would be to say that it is less than that. How do I approach this?

Comment: If I get you right, your argument is that whatever impurity absorbs at 280 nm will add to the total absorbance of the solution. Consequently, one an upper limit for the concentration of the maltose binding protein can be given. This sounds reasonable to me!

Comment: I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). Please do not use markup in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: What are you trying to find? The concentration of MBP alone or the total concentration of all proteins in your solution? If you didn't dilute your solution for measurement, I had c=0.026mM